# MASM - Array permutation output has repeats

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

This is more of a logical question, than an assembly question. The program is supposed to take ten integers from the user and arrange them in the following order: 8, 3, 5, 9, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 7.

The output I get when entering the numbers above is 8, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7. The order is right, but I can't find what's causing the repeats.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
welcome BYTE "Please enter 10 integers to be rearranged.", 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
permutation DWORD 8, 3, 5, 9, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 7
array DWORD 10 DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
MOV EDX, OFFSET welcome
call WriteString
MOV ESI, OFFSET array
MOV ECX, 10

L1:
    call ReadInt
    MOV [ESI], EAX
    ADD ESI, TYPE array
    LOOP L1

MOV EDI, OFFSET permutation
MOV ESI, OFFSET array
MOV ECX, 10

L2:
    MOV EAX, [EDI]
    PUSH ECX
    MOV ECX, 10

    L3:
        CMP EAX, [ESI]
        JE output
        ADD ESI, TYPE array
        back:
        LOOP L3

    ADD EDI, TYPE permutation
    POP ECX
    LOOP L2

    JMP quit

    output:
        MOV EAX, [ESI]
        call WriteInt
        MOV ESI, OFFSET array
        JMP back

quit:
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if you're interpreting the assignment correctly. What should the output be if the input is: `10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19` ?

Comment: The permutation array is supposed to be the order of the indices of the user's array (8th element first, 3rd element second, etc). So the output for your input should be 18, 13, 15, 19, 12, 16, 10, 14, 11, 17.

Comment: I didn't quite ask the right question. What I wanted to know is what your program outputs with that input. It looks like it might not output anything.

Comment: It stores the user's input in an array and outputs those numbers in the order given by the permutation array. And it does output, WriteInt in the Irvine32 library writes the integer stored in EAX.

Comment: If you're telling me that you actually tried running it with that input (10 to 19) and *got output*, I find that very odd indeed. If you just assumed it would work, please actually try it. No output!

Answer (score 0):

It's an assembly question

William wrote :
The output I get when entering the numbers above is 8, 3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 2, 2, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7. The order is right, but I can't find what's causing the repeats.
The reason is that after the ouput you jump back IN the L3 loop! Just reposition the BACK: label after the LOOP L3 instruction.

It's a logical question

William wrote :
The permutation array is supposed to be the order of the indices of the user's array (8th element first, 3rd element second, etc).

A. Since your permutation array contains a zero your sentence should read **(9th element first, 4th element second, etc)**

B. There's no sense in doing `cmp eax,[esi]` for the task at hand.
It's comparing an index [0,9] with an inputted value [-2GB,+2GB-1]

C. You could try to incorporate the next code in your solution

```
mov eax,[edi]
mov eax,[esi+eax*4]  
call WriteInt
```